# A twist on directory walking in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, directory, performance, processing-efficiency

I'd like to do the following:

Given a directory tree:

```
Root
 |_dirA  
 |_dirB  
    |_file1  
    |_file2  
 |_dirC  
    |_dirD  
       |_dirE  
          |_file3  
          |_file4  
 |_dirF  
    |_dirG  
       |_file5  
       |_file6  
       |_file7
```

... I'd like to walk the directory tree and build an array that contains the path to the first file in each directory that has at least one file.  The overall structure may be quite large with many more files than directories, so I'd like to capture just the path to the first file without iterating through all the files in a given directory.  One file is enough. For the above tree, the result should look like an array that contains only:

```
  root/dirB/file1
  root/dirC/dirD/dirE/file3
  root/dirF/dirG/file5
```

I've played with the Dir and Find options in ruby, but my approach feels too brute-force-ish.

Is there an efficient way to code this functionality?  It feels like I am missing some ruby trick here.

Many thanks!

Here's my approach:

```
root="/home/subtest/tsttree/"
Dir.chdir(root)
dir_list=Dir.glob("**/*/") #this invokes recursion
result=Array.new
dir_list.each do |d|
        Dir.chdir(root + d)
        Dir.open(Dir.pwd).each do |filename| 
            next if File.directory? filename  #some directories may contain only other directories so exclude them
            result.push(d + filename)
            break
        end
end
puts result
```

Works, but seems messy.

Comment: Can you please post your approach?

Comment: Disappointing to see this closed.  Anyone wanting to parse a DICOM directory with Ruby will want to do this well.  Optimizing the process is non-trivial and seems to fit the SO format quite well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'pathname'

# My answer to stackoverflow question posted here:
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684736/a-twist-on-directory-walking-in-ruby
class ShallowFinder
  def initialize(root)
    @matches = {}
    @root = Pathname(root)
  end

  def matches
    while match = next_file
      @matches[match.parent.to_s] = match
    end

    @matches.values
  end

  private

  def next_file
    @root.find do |entry|
      Find.prune if previously_matched?(entry)
      return entry if entry.file?
    end
    nil
  end

  def previously_matched?(entry)
    return unless entry.directory?
    @matches.key?(entry.to_s)
  end
end

puts ShallowFinder.new('Root').matches
```

## Outputs:

## Root/B/file1

## Root/C/D/E/file3

## Root/F/G/file5

Comment: Note that this solution will be fast for directories that particularly contain a lot of files.

Comment: I actually think your solution is faster since it doesn't have to traverse multiple times due to your Dir.glob('**/*/') directive. I didn't realize that's how you could recursively get JUST the directories. Nice!

Comment: Thanks!  I was just admiring the tight organization of your method, which I like a lot.

Comment: I just realized I could delete next if (filename == ".") || (filename == "..")  from my code.  Looks like directory? should catch those.